# Pattern matching and list comprehension with binary

Tags: binary, pattern-matching, elixir, list-comprehension

Using list comprehension, elixir allow do pattern matching like that:

```
iex()> for {a,2,c} = ch <- [{1,2,3},{4,5,6},3,4,5], do: c 
[3]
```

But when I'm trying to do something like that with binary, I fail:

```
iex()> for  << b1::size(2), b2::size(3), b3::size(3) >> = <<ch>> <- 'hello', do: b1 
[]
```

Nevertheless, it matches well when standalone:

```
<< b1::size(2), b2::size(3), b3::size(3) >> = <<100>>
"d"
iex(282)> b2
4
iex(283)> b1
1
iex(284)> b3
4
```

It also works well when I pass mattern matching clause as secornd parameter to `for`:

```
iex(286)> for ch <- 'hello', << b1::size(2), b2::size(3), b3::size(3) >> = <<ch>>,  do: b1
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I'm interested if it possible to do something like first example with binary.

Comment: In your second example you're not actually doing a binary comprehension. You have a list there, not a binary. It should be `for << << b1::size(2), b2::size(3), b3::size(3) >> <- "hello" >>, do: b1` but still adding `= ch` to the pattern doesn't work. Not sure why.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong in Elixir because `for << <<a>> = << b1::size(2), b2::size(3), b3::size(3) >> <- "hello" >>, do: b1` returns `[]` in `iex` but throws a compile error when run with `elixir` or `elixirc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what fails:

```rb
<<ch>> <- 'hello'
```

In your very first example you do `var <- list` and later you try `<<var>> <- list` which is not the same by all means.

---

`'hello'` is *the list of integers* in the first place. Check this:

```rb
[104,101,108,108,111]
#⇒ 'hello'
```

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) is *iterating* through the list, one by one. One cannot match binary to an integer as is:

```rb
<<_::size(2), _::size(3), _::size(3)>> = 101
#⇒ ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 101
```

And also:

```rb
<<ch>> = 101
#⇒ ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: 101
```

The latter code example from your question works because you match to an integer and then *explicitly tell to Elixir/Erlang* it’s to be treated as binary by wrapping it with `<< >>`:

```rb
<<b1::size(2), _::size(3), _::size(3)>> = <<101>>
#⇒ "e"
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell Elixir _explicitly_ treat integer as binary in list comprehension? Actually, that's exactly what I want when do `<<ch>>` in `for  << b1::size(2), b2::size(3), b3::size(3) >> = <<ch>> <- 'hello'`

Comment: Obviously not, one cannot match integer to binary anywhere.

Comment: ok, does that mean that comprehension mechanism ignores any modifiers like <<>>, which lead to unability to match binary to integer, whereas I still can use modifiers outside comprehensions to make a match like `<<b1::size(2), _::size(3), _::size(3)>> = <<101>>`?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Comprehension is a match in a nutshell. You cannot matc h integer to binary, hence <<ch>> = 100 won’t work. <<100>> is a completely different thing, it is binary.

Comment: ok, then `for {a,2,c} = ch <- [{1,2,3},{4,5,6},3,4,5], do: c` is a double match? We first match elem from list to `ch`, and then we match it to tuple. We could even do `{a,2,c} = {g,h,j} <- [{1,2,3},{4,5,6},3,4,5], do: c ` if we want. But when it comes to binary, it suddenly stops working.

Comment: Do you understand that 'hello' is a list of integers in the first place?